# Validation not working in partially filled and submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have textboxes and dropdownlist on my form.So i need if any one field blank or dropdown not selected then need to show some error message.

In my code problem is when all the reqired filed not filled then it's working.BUT lets say i have 4 required filed and i only filled 3 and going to submit it,then shows the exception in server side(because validation not properly working).Always error shows in dropdownlists.

Here i have paste the Jquery validation part.

```
                        function shopValidation() {
                    var status = true;
                    if (($.trim($('#txtNewsname').val()) == '') || ($.trim($('#txtNewsaddress').val()) == '')
                        ($.trim($('#txtNewsaddress2').val()) == '') || ($.trim($('#txtNewsaddress3').val()) == '')
                        ($.trim($('#txtNewsreporter').val()) == '') || ($.trim($('#drpNewstypeNews').val()) <= 0)
                        ($.trim($('#drpNewscategory').val()) <= 0) || ($.trim($('#drpLocation').val()) <= 0)) {

                        $("#valmsg_err").removeClass("hidden");

                        if (!ValidateEmail($("#email").val())) {
                            $("#valemail_err").removeClass("hidden");
                        }

                        status = false;
                    }
                    return status
                }
```

So,the other thing is in my validation email function also not working properly.

When i add this function it shows me the error,(It shows me errors unexpected /  & [ required )

[image]

Comment: is there any particular reason you can't format your code when posting? Whitespace forcing scrollbar ....does that seem reasonable to you?

Comment: Why are you not checking the values with empty string of other fields as well such as #drpNewscategory ?

Comment: Any reason your not using the built in validation features of MVC? (adding validation attributes such as `[Required]` to you properties and using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in the view. You get client and serer side validation out of the box with no code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I can't debug the code as it's only partial, it seems quite simple - debug into the `shopValidation()` function and check why it doesn't fulfill the `if` condition and skips to `return status` which is `true` rather than being `false` (if the `if` condition would have been fulfilled, you'd have got a `status = false` which would probably cancel your send).

Comment: In firebug it shows me TypeError: ($.trim(...) == "") is not a function

Comment: I think it's because of my second answer. But anyway, there you go. Just debug your JS code.

Comment: yes. OR function missing is the issue.Could you please look at my second part of the question i just added.(email issue )

Comment: It's because you're trying to use `@` in JS but it's recognized as a Razor expression - you see that Razor colored it yellow? you need to escape it. But submit it as a separate question. You're asking 2 different things.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my previous answer, from dry-reading your code it seems that you've forgotten to put `||` (OR symbols) at the end of each line in the `if` statement.